# Can I trigger click on href element without triggering href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a piece of code that will sometimes need to be triggered by a script, but I don't want it to change the URL on my page. (it messes up the history state for some odd reason)

The code I need to trigger:

```
 $(".photos-bottom .albums #albums li").live("click", function() {
  // my action here
 });

 The code I use to trigger it:
 $(".photos-bottom .albums #albums li:first").trigger("click");
```

The link to click, however I just noticed, it's suppose to click the li and the li is inside of the href so i don't know why it's still clicking it..

```
<a href="#/photos/1/album/42/" rel="address:/photos/1/album/42/">
<li id="42">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `triggerHandler()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

> The .triggerHandler() method behaves similarly to .trigger(), with the following exceptions:
>   The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur (such as a form submission)... [omissis]

Otherwise use `trigger()` with an *`extraparameter`* in the call (see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and in your handler just check the arguments passed. If a parameter was passed then you will prevent the default link action with. `<evt>.preventDefault()`

(note: I assume you handler is attached to links element, not to the list item, since you cannot wrap a list item into a link)

Comment: Thanks, this still changes the URL, however it doesn't break the history as it did before oddly. This works perfectly though.

Comment: I think that the error lies in using `live()` and not `delegate()` or `on()` as the event has to bubble up all the way to the body and so it triggers the link on his way

Answer (score 3):

I think this is caused by live(). This is because the events bubble up to the `<body>` and triggers the click event on the `<a>`. You could use delegate() or on() (jQuery > 1.7) to attache the event handler on the `<a>` and then return false from the function to stop it from triggering the redirect

You could do

```
 $(".photos-bottom .albums #albums a").delegate(".photos-bottom .albums #albums li", "click", function(e) {
  // my action here
     alert("hi");
     //return false so that you stop the immediate propagation of the event
     return false;
 });


 $(".photos-bottom .albums #albums li:first").trigger("click");
```

Fiddle working with delegate http://jsfiddle.net/3CQFK/

Comment: In addition, if you include an `event` parameter, you can prevent bubbling by using `event.StopPropagation()`

Comment: @Dandroid yes of course you could do that, i think i have read somewhere that return false; is equivalent to calling `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's a normal task. There's a function you can call on the event which the callback receives which prevents the browser's default action, called [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault). Your code would be:

```
$(".photos-bottom .albums #albums li").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code here
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I had tried that however it made no difference, Fabrizio's solution works perfectly though. But thanks

Comment: Yep, just saw your LI elements are inside an a. You could delve a bit deeper into how events work, without using jquery. There's a variety of methods that come from the event object passed to the callback, stuff like https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation - hope this helps a bit!